# How to replicate java's ByteBuffer.putLong in php?

Tags: java, php

I need to access from php data from a mysql database whose content is set by a java application, in order to calculate the correct user hash.

I can't seem to replicate the code using php, and I think my problem lies with the long value that PHP can't handle as far as I know

What I have so far:

```
<?php
$g_salt = 'the global salt';
$u_salt = "-2413991061102778232";
$pass = "the password";

$tmp = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($u_salt); $i++) {
 $tmp .= ord($u_salt[$i]);
}
$u_salt = $tmp;

$buffer = $g_salt.$u_salt.$pass;
$hash = bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_SHA256, $buffer));

var_dump($hash);
var_dump("1ee103abe2595681d35c11a27f6dc03a02c5a6ebe01f8abcd7d634a25e050b49");
```

Any idea of how I could do to fix my code ? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

ByteBuffer.putLong writes the salt as a *binary* number as 8 bytes in big-endian order. What you're doing in PHP is something quite different -- it seems that you're taking a base-10 string representation of the salt, then concatenating the *base-10 representation of the ascii value* of each of the characters. Which is kind of a senseless thing to do in any cae.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you are looking for?

```
$hash = hash("sha256", $g_salt . $u_salt. $pass);
```

This simply performs an sha256 hash on the provided string (concatenated) and returns the hex value stored in the $hash variable.  You can get the binary if you like with an additional parameter.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php